# Is a non-geometrically essential knot in a standard solid torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ trivial?

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

Let $V=S^1 \times D^2$ be a standard solid torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $S^1$ and $D^2$ denote a standard  circle and a 2-disk, respectively. Let $K$ be a knot that is embedded inside $V$ so  that $K$ is contained within a 3-ball in $V$ ($K$ is not geometrically essential in $V$). In other words, there is a meridian disk $D_1^2$ such that $K \cap D_1^2=\emptyset $. Can we conclude that K is trivial?

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean that the intersection with every meridian disc is **non-empty**.

Take the [trefoil knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot) and embed it in the torus in such a way that the hole of the torus passes through the center of the trefoil as in the picture in the link.

---

The non-geometrically essential is also not related to the knot not being trivial.

Embed the same trefoil in a ball and put the ball (isometrically) inside the torus.

It is, however, a *trivial loop*, in the sense that you can contract it to a point.

Comment: Ah, I mean the opposite, the knot is not geometrically essential in the solid torus, I edited my post

Comment: @user113715 Yes, non-geometrically essential can also be non-trivial. Edited the answer above.

Comment: I see, thank you so much